# Accessibility of an object in a @Query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I would like to do something like this with `Room` :

```
@Query("UPDATE wallet SET value = quantity + :w.quantity WHERE value = :w.value")
    fun addMoney(w: Wallet)
```

My object `Wallet` is like this :

```
@Entity
data class Wallet(
        @PrimaryKey()
        var value: Int,
        var currency: String,
        var quantity: Int
)
```

And this is how I want to use it :

```
db.walletDao().addMoney(Wallet(5, "USD", 5))
```

But it seem it's impossible to access to the object in the query like this : `:w.quantity`

I have a beauttifull error :

```
    Error:(24, 2) error: mismatched input '.' expecting {<EOF>, ';', ',', '=', '*', '+', '-', '||', '/', '%', '<<', '>>', '&', '|', '<', '<=', '>', '>=', '==', '!=', '<>', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_AND, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_BETWEEN, K_COLLATE, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_GLOB, K_IN, K_INSERT, K_IS, K_ISNULL, K_LIKE, K_MATCH, K_NOT, K_NOTNULL, K_OR, K_PRAGMA, K_REGEXP, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WHERE, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}
    public abstract void addMoney(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                         ^
  mismatched input '.' expecting {<EOF>, ';', '=', '*', '+', '-', '||', '/', '%', '<<', '>>', '&', '|', '<', '<=', '>', '>=', '==', '!=', '<>', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_AND, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_BETWEEN, K_COLLATE, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_GLOB, K_IN, K_INSERT, K_IS, K_ISNULL, K_LIKE, K_MATCH, K_NOT, K_NOTNULL, K_OR, K_PRAGMA, K_REGEXP, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}
```

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not presently supported by Room. It does not support a full expression language, such as the one used by the data binding library. I [requested that feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62760145), and it was rejected.